# Reset StackNavigator inside Drawer contentComponent

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have a DrawerNavigator  with a `Menu` contentComponent that has a StackNavigator inside:

```
export const AppNavigator = DrawerNavigator(
{
    Main: {
        screen: MainNavigator
    }
},
{
    initialRouteName: "Main",
    backBehavior: "initialRoute",
    contentComponent: props => <Menu {...props} />
}
);
```

Menu component

```
export default class Menu extends Component {
  ...
  close() {
    this.props.navigation.navigate("DrawerClose");
  }

  render(){
    return(
      ...
      <MyStackNavigator />
      ...
    )
  }
  ...
}
```

The problem is that when the drawer is closed and reopened the StackNavigator is maintaining its state. I need to reset StackNavigator to its original state.

I can pass the navigation component from the StackNavigator to Menu component and reset it's state when the close button is pressed, but there is no way to handle the case when the user is pressing the back button on the device(or closed with a swipe gesture).

And when the drawer is closed and the StackNavigator is not in initial state pressing the back button on the device will affect the (hidden) StackNavigator.

Comment: There are many such question here and on github about react-navigation being a complete incomprehensible mess that nobody can use, especially not for such a simple thing as opening a simple screen. It can't be used.